# Providing default content for section in layout(rails 3 .erb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Is it possible to provide default content for section in layout if it is not overridden in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using, say a title tag in your head section of your application.html.erb layout file, you could do something as simple as `<%= @title || "Some Default App Content" %>`

Using this same approach, you can use it for content_for and other helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

Now, Rails have `content_for?` method for it: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for